# why put the code in an header

Tags: c, performance, header

Normaly if I make a small code snipet, I usually put it in a whathever.c - file. From the C-file I include a .h -file with other includes or some global varaibles.

I've just heard that the compiler makes the code in a header faster, or somtehing I would love if someone could explain or comment this.

Example code in a header instead of a c-file (could be in a c) ->

```
#define PWM_INTERRUPT \
void InterruptHook(void) \
{ \
    PR4 ^= _SoftPWM_Toggle; \
    \
    PIR3bits.TMR4IF = 0; \
    \
    _asm \
        INCF PR4,0,ACCESS \
        CPFSLT TMR4,ACCESS \
    _endasm \
    \
    /* if(TMR4 > PR4) */ \
        PIR3bits.TMR4IF = 1; \
    \
    SOFT_PWM_PIN ^= 1; \
    \
    _asm \
        RETFIE 1 \
    _endasm \
}
```

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: It's irrelevant, the question is why.

Comment: not entirely irrelevant, since it sounds made up.

Comment: I've heard the same sort of "rumor" before - when you get to the bottom of it, the confusion usually relates to C++ compilers inlining functions (methods) declared in the class header file.  Since inlined functions can be faster than conventionally called ones...  At any rate, its a moot point for the *C* discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put a macro in a separate .c file, because macros are handled by the preprocessor, which is the first step in the compilation process, and separate .c files are handled in the link stage, which is the last step.

Using a macro instead of a function *might* be faster, because it avoids the overhead of a function call.  However, it will slow your compiles down because it compiles the same code multiple times.  It will make your code larger because of redundant copies.  If caching is an issue, it might actually run *slower* because of repeatedly fetching different redundant copies into cache.  There's no way to know for sure without profiling.

If you're talking about the difference between putting a macro in the *same* .c file and a header file, there's no difference performance-wise.  You just would have to copy and paste it into every .c file that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

The "rumor" you heard relates to the way some compilers (most notable C++) tend to inline code that it is placed in a .h file.

This [link](http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2010/11/what-belongs-in-a-c-h-header-file/) (Michael Barr's) provides some very good tips on what belongs (and doesn't belong) in a C header file.

Comment: interesting, in this case it's microchips C18 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything in your *.c/*.cpp file is compiled the preprocessors replaces all of the #include directives with the content of the given *.h file => This end up in a single file for the compiler => No difference in performance between source and header files.

Comment: So it's unimportant where the "main code" or code snipet is placed?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the macro was defined in a header file in order to be used in multiple compilation units (c files) - I doubt it has anything to do with speed.

Comment: that's an odd way then, cause it's only refered from one c-file. That means that I could take the code out of the header into a c file, and as usually still have some defines in the header without losing any performance. And an extra plus... my debugger will go into that function!

Answer (score 0):

Acctually, another answer is: When declaring the high priority interrupt within a macro, the code within the macro is the only one going there, thous doing the interrupt handler fast.

When I define the interrupt outside the macro as a ordinary function, I noticed a lot of code put in the interrupt rutine by the compiler, code I could'nt see whitout using Disassambly Listing in MPLAB IDE.

The later slowing down my rutine fron 16 cycles to 168.